# Delete / Remove Facebook Comment using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a Facebook comment post using the Facebook GRAPH API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008670/how-to-delete-a-facebook-comment-post-using-the-facebook-graph-api)

I'm using FQL Query to get all comments from posts. 
Then using Javascript SDK to post comment:

```
            FB.api("/"+postId+"/comments", 'post', { message: comment }, function(response){
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                  alert('Post was deleted');
                }
            });
```

I try using Javascript SDK and FQL for delete comment but failed.

This question isn't duplicate because I ask how to delete comments using Javascript SDK not Facebook GRAPH API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out using Javascript SDK & previous questions SO:
get **comment_id** variable from field id from FQL table comment.

```
FB.api('/'+comment_id, 'delete', function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post was deleted');
  }
});
```